# What shall we do with answer recommending the same application than a previous answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, policy

I saw that [this answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/1675/903) (since deleted, screenshot below) is recommending the same application than [a previous answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/1567/903). Should I flag answers recommending the same product as another answer?

[image]

Comment: Well that answer is rather bad anyway, so yes do flag it (now deleted). But we should figure out if we allow have two high-quality answers with the same product. Good question!

Comment: Offtopic: How can you see a deleted answer? Thought you need 10k rep for that?

Comment: 10K or being mod I believe.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it depends on the answer.

- (a) If the answer is (nearly) a **copy or a subset** (e.g., a link and some facts that are also mentioned in the previous answer), flag it. It should probably be deleted.
- (b) If the answer is nearly the same and only **adds trivial information or facts**, flag it. It should probably be an edit to the previous answer.
- (c) If the answer contains a **personal and different** review/rating, description of a workflow, warnings and caveats, etc. (i.e., *it is a good answer*), keep it. It can be very valuable to have several answers all recommending the same tool, because they add different perspectives.

  - What would be the alternative? Such personal experiences shouldn’t be added to the answer of another person (the edit would be too radical), but I think they are too valuable to dismiss them.
- (d) If the answer contains personal experiences like in (c) but it isn’t substantially different to the previous answer, it isn’t really useful to the question but neither should it be flagged/deleted. I assume this will happen rarely (maybe when both persons are writing their answers nearly at the same time and they had exactly the same use case).

If you see an answer that more or less contains everything you would have said, you should upvote it instead of adding an own answer. Edit it if some facts are missing. Only create an own answer if your *personal* experience with this tool could make a difference to OP’s decision.

Comment: Nice example in [this question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2527/60): [Nick Wilde](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/2543/60) and [Izzy](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/2544/60) answered almost at the same time, recommended the same software, but described a different workflow/solution.

Comment: What about if one answer has screenshots and the other doesn't? Does that count as trivial information and facts?

Comment: @aman207: Probably depends on the individual case. In my opinion: When the screenshot only shows the main GUI (as if it could have been taken from the official website), it’s trivial. When the screenshot(s) show/highlight specific requested features, or explain how to do something, a new answer might be appropriate.